# A broken Stack Exchange Compensation link

Tags: bug, broken-link, blog

I was reading [How much you should pay your developers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/how-much-should-you-pay-developers/) blog post and decided to read a [Stack Exchange Developer Compensation PDF](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/Stack-Exchange-Developer-Compensation.pdf) which is posted at the bottom of the blog post, but the link doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: Pro-tip: if you find a dead link, try [the web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150206125709/http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/Stack-Exchange-Developer-Compensation.pdf).

Comment: This was reported on Github: https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/issues/114.  It's available at https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/files/60428/Stack-Exchange-Developer-Compensation.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am logged in to Disqus. Below the comments it says:

*PDF link is broken. Old version available here*:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150206125709/https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/Stack-Exchange-Developer-Compensation.pdf